Switch terminal to "line mode" instead of "character mode"
In Neovim's default terminal emulator, every entered character gets sent immediately to a shell running in the background (instead of waiting until you press enter on an entire line). One consequence is that, for example, you can't type cp /foo/bar, and change cp to cd by using standard vim motions (instead of just pressing backspace many times).
Is there a way to have the terminal commands sent once I hit Enter, so that I can use the standard vim motions for editing commands?

A Vim terminal in Terminal-Normal mode is a like a readonly buffer: you can’t edit what the shell already received. See :help :terminal.
You can either

Edit commands in a separate buffer, thank yank/paste them into the terminal buffer
Enable your shell’s vi editing mode (Bash: set -o vi; Zsh: bindkey -v)


If I remember, more details to come when I’m not travelling. In the meantime, kind souls should feel free to [edit] and add ;)
